# Angularjs binding not updating after clicking confirm

Tags: angularjs, binding

I've just started learning ng1 after accepting a job to maintain and improve an in-house application.

I've found a number of instances where values within a table are not updating upon clicking confirm (resetting to zero in some instances instead.) They are, however, updating in the console. Also, after the values reset to zero, when you update input values once more the fields immediately revert back their correct values.

A solution my predecessor has come to is to use disabled inputs for the values as these update correctly. This is a hack, however, and my boss would like me to correct it.

Please see below for a more basic example of the issue:

```
 coeficienteFactory.saveProjectCoeficient(vm.id_project, vm.coeficient)
            .then(function succesCallback(response) {

                console.log('true!!!');
                vm.confirm = true;
                setTimeout(function(){ vm.confirm = false; console.log("disappears!!!")}, 2000);

            }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {  
                console.log(response)
            });
```

The above example will trigger vm.confirm and a success message will appear in the view through ng-show. Two seconds later, however, the "disappears" message will appear in the console but the confirm message does not respond accordingly in the view...

This is clearly a fundamental misunderstanding on my part and is something I have to learn quickly!

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Angular version - `$timeout` - which causes a digest cycle. Change:

```
setTimeout(function(){ vm.confirm = false; console.log("disappears!!!")}, 2000);
```

To:

```
$timeout(() => {
    vm.confirm = false;
    console.log('disappears!!!');
}, 2000);
```

Be sure to also inject `$timeout` in your controller.

Comment: This worked in the more simple example given. Many thanks.

It is not applicable to the main problem, however. Should I create a new post with a clear example provided?

Comment: @jamesbcn If you have a different problem that isn't solved by the $timeout then I would make a separate post.